# Qt4.7 -- "QtCore/QFile: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have to set up a Qt development environment for my GUI class. I am working through a tutorial and was instructed to include the `<QTCore/QFile>` header in my implementation file. However, I cannot build the project because the above header file is not found.

I am not sure what I am missing here -- I installed Qt-Creator and all of the deps from the Debian package manager (currently using Wheezy). The Qt 4.7 documentation in IDE also has a section on the above header files, and yet it can't seem to locate them... odd.

NOTE: Header should have read `<QtCore/QFile`>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Just `#include <QFile>` will be more compatible with Qt5. Also note the capital T you have, it should have been `#include <QtCore/QFile>` - remember unix/linux file systems are case sensitive.
2. You looked at the library file, not the include files. Those are different things in C/C++.
3. As trojanfoe correctly mentioned - you are probably missing the development packages of Qt4.

Comment: And yes, the lower-case t fixed it. The solution was staring me in the face the whole time ... now I feel like an idiot :S